# Response.Redirect results in malformed relative path

Tags: configuration, iis-7, httpresponse, response.redirect

I have a problem with getting Response.Redirect to work properly on my ASP.NET web forms site running on IIS 7 behind SSL. The redirect path is appended to my current path, and I cannot find out which configuration is causing this.

My execution code is :

```
string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + '/';
Response.Redirect(Server.UrlEncode(baseUrl + "Default.aspx"), true);
```

Relevant parts of my web.config are :

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />

  and

<httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

Executed from the directory Ui/Forms, I get this
https://mysite.edu/Ui/Forms/https%3a%2f%2fmysite.edu%2fUi%2fForms%2fhttps%253a%2f%2fmysite.edu%2fDefaul.aspx

Any configuration pointers or links are helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer and forgot to mention a key piece of the puzzle. The button firing the code above was in an UpdatePanel, and I forgot to add a PostBackTrigger to the update panel for that button.  Response.Redirect then works.

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
</Triggers>
```